# Repeated reputation notification for same upvote

Tags: bug, status-completed

Every time I visit a new SO page, I get the same "+10" reputation change notification:

[image]

After clicking on the notification dropdown, it's cleared, but as soon as I visit another SO page (or for that matter another network page, such as crossvalidated.com) the "+10" is back for the same upvote. Logging out, nuking all cookies, and logging back in did not resolve the issue.

I see nothing particularly special about [the upvote that caused the notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273934/confusion-matrix-from-rpart/21274190#21274190), so I'm not sure what's going on here. Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact [I keep seeing a notification](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aIwUx.png), no matter what...

Comment: Gosh nobody's going to let a little server glitch get by unnoticed...

Comment: Maybe clear your cookies and relog.

Comment: @SantaClaus thanks for the suggestion -- logging out and back in did not resolve the issue. I've updated the post to mention this.

Comment: Make sure you clear all of your browser cookies. Logging out should clear them for you, but there are circumstances when it will not.

Comment: This also happens for "unread inbox messages". Using browser Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m.

Comment: OK, nuked all cookies, logged out and back in, and the issue persists.

Comment: FYI [Stubborn +24 in the topbar that won't go away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236388/163250) same problem?

Comment: It is, @Cupcake

Comment: @Cupcake yes, seems to be network-wide

Comment: Exactly same problem here.

Comment: Clearing all cookies related to StackExchange sites does not mitigate the problem.

Comment: This is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was related to the Redis upgrade earlier this evening, and should now be resolved.