# Repetitive notification alert on each and every site I visit

Tags: support

### Clarification:Its not a possible [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265326/repeated-reputation-notification-for-same-upvote) as other users seem to because in that post the question is about the same rep notification twice whereas my post is on the same notification alert on different pages.

Previously when any notification would appear I would click it and then the notification disappeared.It would not appear again on any site you visit as you have already checked your notification.

[image: Screen shot regarding the rep notification]

In the above picture you can see that I have first checked my notification on SE site and then the notification disappears but when when I click on DA,Tor i again receive this notification and I need to double click for the notification to disappear.

It never happened like this before .Then why am I receiving this notification again and again on each and every site I visit?

Comment: Is this still happening to you now? If not, then it was a Redis issue, just like with the other question that your question is closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: what is this Redis issue